# AWS Eventbridge Scheduler not started

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge, aws-java-sdk

**I have created AWS eventbridge scheduler for ECS using java SDKs, But it not starting but if edit it and save it starting, So please help me**

I created scheduler using schedulerClient, ECS Target.

When I am creating scheduler using SDK it creating, But scheduler not runing
But When I am editing it and making change like time and saving it again then starting

scheduler created, But not started

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.